# Show imageview when reach the end of the listview with scroll

Tags: java, android, listview, scroll

I wanna show imageview already included in layout xml when user reach the end of the listview with scroll , i switch to Visible.GONE while loading the activity with onCreate method and than try to show the imageview when user reach the end of the scroll on the listview. How can i implement this ?

Comment: ok, what's the question? What is the trouble?

Comment: is it not obvious , I am trying to implement this

Answer (score 0):

I know simple solution but without using XML files.

`ListView` have methods for adding header and footer views. Just wrote in your code something like this:

```
listView.addFooterView(imageView);
```

See [ListView.addFooterView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View%29) for reference.